# Is catching an exception really as easy as this? Should I be doing more?

Tags: php

In the code I'm looking at right now, there are many functions that look as follows.

```
function doSomething() {
  if (somethingDoesntLookRight) {
    throw new Exception("Error message");
  }
  // continue code here if exception not thrown
}
```

And I'm planning on just wrapping these exceptions in a try/catch but I feel like maybe I should be doing more to make sure the exception doesn't happen, or is this the right way to handle it?

```
function doSomething() {
  try {
    if (somethingDoesntLookRight) {
      throw new Exception("Error message");
    }
    // continue code here if exception not thrown
  } catch(Exception $e) {
    // Log error message here using $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it's that easy :)

Comment: you can read the full documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Wow thank you :) This is great ;)

Comment: Except you also want to catch non-exceptions. But that's another story.